# Choosing the right Google API (Maps Vs Places)

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am fairly new to Google APIs.

My business purpose is to get a list of hotels in my area.

From the Google API list, I figured that either Google Map Engine API or Google Places API would be ideal.

Google MAP Engine API - was chosen because in the documentation it said that we can access public data.
Google Places API - was chosen because in the documentation it said that we can access places in a locality.

Could anyone help on whether I have chosen the right API? And can my business purpose be achieved using Google APIs?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know google api v3
if you need to make a web based applicaton to do anything with google map you first need to include javascript api v3.

other apis/libraries sit on top of that
like : Places library (or you say api) , drawing library , overlays , weather etc

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

if you scroll down a bit on contents you will see all the extra libraries there (including the place library which you need) As google says: "The Places API is integrated into the Google Maps JavaScript API as a JavaScript library."

so JUST inlude google javascritp api v3 and you get everything.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

use example above and change the type from ['store'] to ['lodging'] to get all the hotels near the lat,lon specified.